# Active Record - select with SQL returns string instead of original class

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, time, rails-activerecord

I have a database of users and appointments. The appointments have `start_time` and `end_time` in TimeWithZone format. I want to determine which users have exceeded a certain total duration. Unfortunately the appointments table doesn't have duration built-in, so I have to calculate it myself.

If I subtract the start_time from end_time it returns a float, which is perfect for me.

```
Appointment.first.end_date - Appointment.first.start_time
=> 3600.0
(Appointment.first.end_date - Appointment.first.start_time).class
=> Float
```

If I run it on my whole table and try to create a new column, it returns a string:

```
Appointment.select("end_time - start_time as duration").first.duration
=> "01:00:00"
Appointment.select("end_time - start_time as duration").first.duration.class
=> String
```

I'm not sure why the type changed and how to cast it back to a float, or any class easier to deal with. Ideally, my end query would look something like:

`User.joins(:appointments).select("users.id", "end_time - start_time as duration").group("users.id").having("SUM(duration) >= ?", timelimit)`with `timelimit` depending on the max duration and whatever units I get

1) Why do I get different results for what are very similar commands

2) How do create a new column that's the duration of each appointment, based on their end and start times?

Comment: Are start_date and start_time different? What does `Appointment.select("end_time - start_time as duration").first` return?

Comment: You're subtracting `Date`s in Ruby but `time`s in the database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get different results because one is done by Ruby and the other is done by SQL. There's no reason why both should do the same thing.

You can use TIME_TO_SEC if you are using MySQL https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-to-sec

```
Appointment.select("TIME_TO_SEC(end_time - start_time) as duration")
```

`TIME_TO_SEC` converts the string "01:00:00" to seconds.

```
mysql> SELECT TIME_TO_SEC("01:00:00");
+-------------------------+
| TIME_TO_SEC("01:00:00") |
+-------------------------+
|                    3600 |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0,05 sec)
```

Comment: Thanks! If it's relevant for anyone who finds this in the future, postgres does not have TIME_TO_SEC, so you have to use something like Appointment.select("EXTRACT (EPOCH FROM end_time - start_time) as duration") 

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816544/convert-time-to-seconds-in-postgresql