# Is it possible to convert a 24 hour time stamp into seconds inside of a SQL query?

Tags: sql, postgresql

In a database we are storing times as 24 hour time stamps. For example '13:15:00'. Im just curious if theres a way to convert these times into seconds inside of a sql query... because I am trying to grab records only between a specific time range. I googled and found TIME_FORMAT(), but that does not seem to be working. Thanks!

EDIT: using postgresql

Comment: Are you using MySQL or Postgresql?

Comment: @jarlh sorry, using Postgresql

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert time to seconds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816544/convert-time-to-seconds-in-postgresql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this does what you want:

```
select extract(epoch from '13:15:00'::time)
```

Comment: Thats it... thanks so much!