# SQL split with an interval data type

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have these SQL statements:

```
SELECT avg_freq 
FROM tlm.data_qa_tele_freq(du.id, 1001, now()::timestamp - interval '0.5 day', now()::timestamp),
```

which return an interval like this 00:00:00, that is hour:minutes:second. Which I want to split with ':', so the total interval in seconds would be: second+minute*60+hour*3600

So

```
STRING_SPLIT( SELECT avg_freq FROM tlm.data_qa_tele_freq(183, 1001, now()::timestamp - interval '0.5 day', now()::timestamp),':')
```

> ERROR:  syntax error at or near "STRING_SPLIT"

So

```
SELECT CAST (avg_freq as TEXT) FROM STRING_SPLIT (tlm.data_qa_tele_freq(183, 1001, now()::timestamp - interval '0.5 day', now()::timestamp),':')
```

> ERROR:  function string_split(record, unknown) does not exist

> LINE 1:

> SELECT CAST (avg_freq as TEXT) FROM STRING_SPLIT (tlm.da...
> ^ HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add
> explicit type casts.

Comment: You can use `to_char()` to format the interval the way you want it.

Comment: What exactly is the return type of your function?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert time to seconds in PostgreSQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816544/convert-time-to-seconds-in-postgresql)

Comment: It return 00:01:33.833333 (interval). the function tlm.data_qa_tele_freq makes a differences between times.

Comment: `select extract(epoch from  '00:01:33.833333'::interval ); 93.833333` or for longer period of time, `select extract(epoch from  '22:45:35.156876'::interval ); 81935.156876` ? If this is not what you want then you will need provide example data with inputs and expected outputs.